# Program interface hang when restoring from minimized state

Tags: .net, interface, response, freeze

What can cause the interface of program "hang" when *user restores it or just comes to the computer after some time, or accessing the computer on which the program is run with same remote desktop user twice*?..The program doesn't hang (process is responding), but interface becomes unresponsive. User can minimize/maximize it, but cant operate with its contents. I, myself, cant even reproduce such hang when debugging program. But all customers report it from time to time in all the programs i wrote. 
May be its fault of some third party dll's we use?..In all my software i used: Devexpress(grid, report, mdimanager), NLog, Stimulsoft Reports(reports). For opening new tabs in mdimanager i usually use BackgroundWorker, but i dont think it's some sort of his synchronization problem, because but appears spontaneously and doesn't throw any exception; just interface hang and that's all.
May be my question is silly, but i cant find any information about such bug or just cant describe it properly in search request.
Will be grateful for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code its hard to say, but based on the behavior it sounds like a threading issue in your UI code. Something is causing it to deadlock. Are you updating the UI from the background worker when the UI is restored. If you are updating the UI from another thread you must use an `Invoke` method. You cannot update the UI thread from another thread.

Comment: No, nothing happens in code on Maximize/Minimize..When im updating anything in UI from the thread-i usually use BeginInvoke. Sorry, but i cant paste code here, because dont even know, what part of it can do that.

Comment: @nihi do you <b>always</b> use BeginInvoke, or just usually. You cannot update the UI outside of the UI thread. It may work sometimes, but will lock up or cause other issues other times. Another thing to check is that you are running in the STAThread apartment model. But this really sounds like a thread synchronization issue. Check your OnPaint method (if you are overriding it) or OnSizeChanged (if you are overriding that) for threading issues. Are you using any collections in your background worker threads. Are those collections being read in the worker and modified in the UI thread?

Comment: I'll definitely check all that, thank you. But i dont override OnPaint or OnSizeChanged.. Tho this really seems like sync problem..